# Webdriverio with Crossbrowsertesting --> Bitbar migration

Tags: webdriver-io, bitbar

have you successfully done migration from Crossbrowsertesting to Bitbar? (their new service)   We use the service mainly for desktop browsers.
When it was Crossbrowsertesting, we used @wdio/crossbrowsertesting-service.
But what should we use now?

Just to change test url does not take effect.

https://support.smartbear.com/bitbar/docs/en/web-app-tests/crossbrowsertesting-to-bitbar-migration.html

Thank you

We tried:

- change testing url
- changing browser capabilities